# Telegram bot sends photos only after me sending something in the chat

Tags: java, telegram-bot

There is a bot that takes top movies pictures from the website and sends them to chat. The problem is that it sends them only when you enter any message, and by sending messages over and over again, the bot starts sending them accordingly from the beginning. I tried to push sending in a separate thread, but it didn't work(perhaps I was doing wrong). Overall, I need the bot to send photo images from the array, say, every 30 minutes.

Class which is responsible for making the images links array:

```
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class NewFilms {
        private static ArrayList<String> absoluteUrls = new ArrayList<>();

        public NewFilms() throws IOException {
            createArrayOfImages();
        }

        private static void  createArrayOfImages() throws IOException {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://gidonline.in/").get();
            List<Element> imageElements = document.select("img[src$=120x170.jpg]");
            for (Element element : imageElements) {
                absoluteUrls.add(element.absUrl("src"));
            }
        }

        public static ArrayList<String> getAbsoluteUrls() {
            return absoluteUrls;
        }
    }
```

My bot's class:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendPhoto;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.PhotoSize;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardRemove;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Bot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("TelegramBot successfully started!");

    }

    private void sendMsg(Message message, String text) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage()
                .setChatId(message.getChatId().toString())
                .setText(text);
        try {
            setButtons(sendMessage);
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendPhotoMsg(Message message) {
        List<PhotoSize> photos = message.getPhoto();
        String f_ID = photos.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PhotoSize::getFileSize).reversed())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null).getFileId();
        int f_WIDTH = photos.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PhotoSize::getFileSize).reversed())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null).getWidth();
        int f_HEIGHT = photos.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PhotoSize::getHeight).reversed())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null).getHeight();
        // set photo caption
        String caption = "file_id " + f_ID + "\nwidth: " + f_WIDTH + "\nheight: " + f_HEIGHT;

        SendPhoto msg = new SendPhoto()
                .setChatId(message.getChatId())
                .setPhoto(f_ID)
                .setCaption(caption);
        try {
            execute(msg);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        class FiveMinutes extends Thread {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sendEveryFiveMin();
                } catch (IOException | TelegramApiException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void sendEveryFiveMin() throws IOException, TelegramApiException, InterruptedException {
                new NewFilms();
                for (String imagesLink : NewFilms.getAbsoluteUrls()) {
                    SendPhoto msgs = new SendPhoto()
                            .setPhoto(imagesLink)
                            .setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
                    try {
                        execute(msgs);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
            }
        }

        Model model = new Model();
        Message message = update.getMessage();

        FiveMinutes newThread = new FiveMinutes(); //вот он тот самый поток:)
        newThread.start();

        if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
            switch (message.getText()) {
                case "/help":
                    sendMsg(message, "Чем могу помочь?");
                    break;
                case "/settings":
                    sendMsg(message, "Что будем настраивать?");
                    break;
                case "/hide":
                    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage()
                            .setText("Клавиатура спрячена.")
                            .setChatId(message.getChatId());
                    ReplyKeyboardRemove replyKeyboardRemove = new ReplyKeyboardRemove();
                    sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardRemove);
                    try {
                        execute(sendMessage);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case "/back":
                    SendMessage sendMessage1 = new SendMessage()
                            .setText("Клавиатура возвращена.")
                            .setChatId(message.getChatId());
                    ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
                    sendMessage1.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
                    try {
                        setButtons(sendMessage1);
                        execute(sendMessage1);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^@.+$");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message.getText());
                    if (matcher.matches()) {
                        try {
                            sendMsg(message, Weather.getWeather(message.getText().substring(1, message.getText().length()), model));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            sendMsg(message, "Такой город не найден!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^.+$");
                        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(message.getText());
                        SendMessage backMessage = new SendMessage()
                                .setChatId(message.getChatId().toString())
                                .setText(new StringBuilder(message.getText()).reverse().toString());
                        //backMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
                        try{
                            execute(backMessage);
                        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        else if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasPhoto()) {
            assert message != null;
            sendPhotoMsg(message);
        }
    }

    public void setButtons(SendMessage sendMessage) {
        ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
        sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard(false);

        List<KeyboardRow> keyboardRowList = new ArrayList<>();

        KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
        keyboardFirstRow.add(new KeyboardButton("/help"));
        keyboardFirstRow.add(new KeyboardButton("/settings"));
        keyboardFirstRow.add(new KeyboardButton("/info"));
        keyboardRowList.add(keyboardFirstRow);

        KeyboardRow keyboardSecondRow = new KeyboardRow();
        keyboardSecondRow.add(new KeyboardButton("/pic"));
        keyboardSecondRow.add(new KeyboardButton("/hide"));
        keyboardSecondRow.add(new KeyboardButton("/back"));
        keyboardRowList.add(keyboardSecondRow);

        replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboardRowList);
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "name-of-the-bot";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "bot-token";
    }
}
```